# UITableView data displays in simulator, but not on actual device

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have created a custom tableViewCell and am populating it with data. The data appears fine in the simulator but does not populate on the device. Below is my code. Thanks for any help in advance this one is really catching me.

viewDidLoad:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
[self initColors];
[self initDB];
[self.pointsTableView reloadData ];
}
```

numberOfSections/RowsInSection:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
return [[self.dealNameCountDict allKeys]count];
}
```

cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
ProfileTableViewCell *cell = (ProfileTableViewCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ProfileTableViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

if (cell == nil)
{
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ProfileTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
}

// Configure the cell...
NSArray<NSString*> *keys = [self.dealNameCountDict allKeys];
NSString *k = [keys objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

// should be a dictionary for businessNameLabel
cell.textLabel.text = k;
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[self.dealNameCountDict objectForKey:k] stringValue];


return cell;
}
```

Comment: @Mr JonesisMe check this setting -: Select Project -> Build Setting -> Architecture Tab - > Build Release to YES

Comment: `NSArray<NSString*> *keys = [self.dealNameCountDict allKeys];` shouldn't be recommended because the order of the keys isn't guaranteed. Is `- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section` called? What does `-initDB`? Is it async? Do you see at list the tableView in device? Could it be a different model on simulator and a layout/constraint issue?

Comment: @Larme  `(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section` is called. I think that `dealNameCountDict` is created from an async Firebase call though.

Comment: And what value does it returns?

Comment: @Larme it returns a dictionary and it's keys will populate my tableview

Comment: Does it returns 0 on device? It clearly doesn’t return a dict but an integer. Could you log the value returned by that method? And what is initDB?

Comment: @TusharSharma Build Release is set to yes. This doesn't fix anything

Comment: @Larme `initDB` is old code for a database that is no longer being used. I can comment it out and still have the same outcome. `dealNameCountDict` is a dictionary. I am counting the keys to return an integer for the numberofRowsInSection.  I am using the keys themselves to populate the table view cells.

Comment: If the method returns 0 on your device because your dictionary is empty at the moment it's called, that could be something to follow up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably populating your dictionary after reloading the table view. The device runs usually a little faster than the simulator - so if you get the data asynchonously, that may be the reason.

Try reloading the table view in the setter of your dictionary.

```
- (void)setMyDictionary:(NSDictionary*)myDictionary {

   _myDictionary = myDictionary;
   [table reloadData];

}
```

Comment: That is what I ended up doing. Thanks.

Comment: @MrJonesIsMe please Mark this as answered then :)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there was another file local function which initialized `dealNameCountDict` after the table had been created and after `viewDidLoad` was called. I just added

`[self.pointsTableView reloadData ];`

to the end of that function and this seems to have solved the async issues.